# Is it possible to transform the types in a parameter pack?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, c++11

Is it possible to transform the types of a parameter pack and pass it on?

E.g. given the following:

```
template<class... Args> struct X {};
template<class T> struct make_pointer     { typedef T* type; };
template<class T> struct make_pointer<T*> { typedef T* type; };
```

Can we define a template `magic` or something similar so that the following assertion holds:

```
typedef magic<X, make_pointer, int, char>::type A;
typedef X<int*, char*> B;
static_assert(is_same<A, B>::value, ":(");
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes we can do that

```
template<template<typename...> class List, 
         template<typename> class Mod, 
         typename ...Args>
struct magic {
    typedef List<typename Mod<Args>::type...> type;
};
```

Comment: Ah, *§14.5.3/5* even includes examples which i somehow managed to overlook :)