# How to parse a static const std::string in compilation time?

Tags: c++, string, parsing, compilation-time

I have some SQL queries with binds in my C++ code, those queries are `static const std::string`, because those queries are complex it is very easy to be wrong with some details. I would like to do some very basic checks in compilation time, for example counting the number of commas or `:` character.

Comment: You can achieve that with `constexpr` functions and metaprogramming basically

Comment: Instead of bending over backwards to get this done at compile time (presumably because you are afraid of the impact these checks might have on performance), may I suggest two commonly employed alternatives? 1) Make those checks conditionally-compiled for debug versions of your application only (`#ifndef NDEBUG ...`). You get the checks during development, without any impact on release performance. 2) _Measure, optimize, measure_. Compared with a SQL connect / query, some string checking is most likely taking a tiny, negligible amount of time. You might not even _have_ a performance problem.

Comment: @DevSolar I think early error checking is the real reason to parse at compile time, not performance. The OP actually said so: "I would like to do some very basic checks in compilation time"

Answer (score 5):

You can't. A `static const std::string` doesn't exist at compile time.

String literals are possible with `constexpr` functions, but not `std::string` objects.

Answer (score 4):

You can't parse `std::string` at compile time, because it can be constructed only at run-time. But there are nice answers at StackOverflow that describes how to define and manipulate compile-time strings:

1. [Compile time string encryption using constexpr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32287125/compile-time-string-encryption-using-constexpr).
2. [Conveniently Declaring Compile-Time Strings in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858141/conveniently-declaring-compile-time-strings-in-c)

They refer to of [Scott Schurr's str_const](https://github.com/boostcon/cppnow_presentations_2012/blob/master/wed/schurr_cpp11_tools_for_class_authors.pdf?raw=true) starting at page 29:

```
class str_const { // constexpr string
private:
  const char* const p_;
  const std::size_t sz_;
public:
  template<std::size_t N>
  constexpr str_const(const char(&a)[N]) : // ctor
    p_(a), sz_(N-1) {}
  constexpr char operator[](std::size_t n) { // []
    return n < sz_ ? p_[n] : throw std::out_of_range("");
  }
  constexpr std::size_t size() { return sz_; } // size()
};
```

See how [Jason Turner's constexpr JSON parser](https://github.com/lefticus/constexpr_all_the_things/tree/master/src/include) works. It is able to parse a whole JSON string at compile time, so it should be possible to parse and validate SQL at compile time. You just need to use Scott's std_const, or Jason's static_string for that.

Here is a trivial extension that makes it play nicer with `std::string_view`, and have a compile-time `substr` method:

```
class str_const {
private:
  const char* const p_;
  const std::size_t sz_;
public:
  template<std::size_t N>
  constexpr str_const(const char(&a)[N]) :
    p_(a), sz_(N-1) {}
  constexpr str_const(const std::string_view & sv) :
    p_(sv.begin()), sz_(sv.size()) {}
  constexpr operator std::string_view() const
  { return {p_, sz_}; }

  constexpr char operator[](std::size_t n) const { // []
    return n < sz_ ? p_[n] : throw std::out_of_range("");
  }
  constexpr std::size_t size() const { return sz_; } // size()
  constexpr const char*c_str() const { return p_; }

  constexpr const char*begin() const { return p_; }
  constexpr const char*end() const { return p_ + sz_; }
  constexpr str_const substr(unsigned from, unsigned size) const
  {
    return from+size <= sz_ ? std::string_view{p_ + from, size} : throw std::out_of_range("");
  }
};
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream& out, str_const str) {
   return out << std::string_view(str);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::string` doesn't exist at compile time. If you want to have such a behavior, you can use the string literals with constexpr as below:

```
constexpr const char* const var = "string";
```

To understand more about this, please see the assemble code generated for this:

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    constexpr const char* const str = "string";
    const std::string test = "test";
}
```

With `X86-64 Clang 6.0.0` compiler and with `0` optimizations,

```
constexpr const char* const str = "string";
```

generated below code:

```
subq    $80, %rsp
movq    $.L.str, -8(%rbp)
leaq    -48(%rbp), %rax

.L.str:
        .asciz  "string"
```

and for `const std::string test = "test";` below code is generated (Just a snippet)
So it calls the `std::allocater` which allocates the memory on the heap and then constructs the string object.

```
        movq    %rax, %rdi
        movq    %rax, -72(%rbp)         # 8-byte Spill
        callq   std::allocator<char>::allocator() [complete object constructor]
        movl    $.L.str.1, %ecx
        movl    %ecx, %esi
        leaq    -40(%rbp), %rdi
        movq    -72(%rbp), %rdx         # 8-byte Reload
        callq   std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)
        jmp     .LBB0_1
```

Comment: if `std::string` is short enough for SSO, can't `static const std::string`  still be a compile time object?

Answer (score 0):

As Sebastian already mentioned, you can't if you need `std::string`. But maybe, as an alternative, you can do something like `constexpr auto query = "MY SQL QUERY";` I don't know if you are allowed to modify the type of the queries.
Then at runtime, `query` can be used to construct a `std::string` if you need one. Checks at compile time can also be done.

The disadvantage of course is that it is copied at runtime when creating a std::string.