# Compile-time std::string obfuscation

Tags: c++, obfuscation

I trying to write function, for compile-time hide (obfuscate) text strings in the binary code. Purpose: to disable easy search and modify text messages with binary editor.

Algorithm is simple: convert chars within string to `deltas`, i. e. string `abcd` must be saved in the binary file as `a\001\001\001`.

I wrote the following code, it works:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

constexpr std::string str_encrypt(const char *str) {
    std::string rc; 
    unsigned char x = 0, c;
    while(c = *str++) {
         rc.push_back(c - x); 
        x = c;
    }   
    return rc; 
}

std::string str_decrypt(const std::string &str) {
    std::string rc; 
    unsigned char x = 0;
    for(unsigned char c : str)
        rc.push_back(x += c); 
    return rc; 
}

const std::string hello(str_encrypt("Hello, world!"));

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    for(unsigned char c : hello)
        printf("%d ", c); 
    putchar('\n');
    printf("S=[%s]\n", str_decrypt(hello).c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

But string still is not "encrypted" within binary file:

```
$ c++ -std=c++2b -O2 constexpr.cpp  && strings a.out | grep Hello
Hello, world!
```

When I change `constexpr` to `consteval`, I see compilation error:

```
$ c++ -std=c++2b -O2 constexpr.cpp 
constexpr.cpp:23:36: error: ‘std::string{std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::_Alloc_hider{((char*)(&<anonymous>.std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::<anonymous>.std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::<unnamed union>::_M_local_buf))}, 13, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::<unnamed union>{char [16]{'H', '\035', '\007', '\000', '\003', '\37777777675', '\37777777764', 'W', '\37777777770', '\003', '\37777777772', '\37777777770', '\37777777675', 0}}}’ is not a constant expression
   23 | const std::string hello(str_encrypt("Hello, world!"));
```

My question:
Is possible to write such compile-time encryption? If so, please suggest, how to do.

*My compiler: g++ (GCC) 12.2.1 20230201*

Comment: If you don't want to reinvent a will you can use https://github.com/JustasMasiulis/xorstr

Comment: Have a look at this too : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32287125/compile-time-string-encryption-using-constexpr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that str_encrypt is not evaluated at compile time.

> When I change constexpr to consteval, I see compilation error

This is a hint, when we switch to consteval, which requires `str_encrypt` to be an immediate / compile time function, the compiler gives an error.

Since C++20, `std::string` can be used in compile time contexts, if it is a transient allocation, i.e. the string must be destroyed before exiting the compile time context.

In this example this is not the case, so `str_encrypt` cannot be a compile time function.

If we had put:

`constexpr std::string hello(str_encrypt("Hello, world!"));`

Then we would see a similar error to using consteval on `str_encrypt`.

However, arrays or `std::arrays` can be constexpr.

So if instead of returning a `std::string` we return `std::array` then the example can work as expected.

This modified example works with g++ / clang++ and requires C++17.
Using `consteval` would be advisable, to force compile time evaluation, but of course requires C++20.

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <array>

template <size_t N>
constexpr std::array<char, N> str_encrypt(const char (&str)[N]) {
    std::array<char, N> output{};
    unsigned char x = 0, c = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        c = str[i];
        output[i] = (c - x);
        x = c;
    }
    return output;
}

template <size_t N>
std::string str_decrypt(const std::array<char, N> &str) {
    std::string rc;
    unsigned char x = 0;
    for(unsigned char c : str)
        rc.push_back(x += c);
    return rc;
}

constexpr auto hello = str_encrypt("Hello, world!");

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    for(unsigned char c : hello)
        printf("%d ", c);
    putchar('\n');
    printf("S=[%s]\n", str_decrypt(hello).c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./example
72 29 7 0 3 189 244 87 248 3 250 248 189 223
S=[Hello, world!]
```

The string "Hello, world!" is not in the binary, nor is the `str_encrypt` function.

```
$ strings example | grep Hello

$ objdump -t -C example | grep str_
0000000000001302  w    F .text  00000000000000a6              std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > str_decrypt<14ul>(std::array<char, 14ul> const&)
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/vPj3bW6Yz