# Compile-time string compression with C++17 and earlier

Tags: c++, c++17

I have an application that uses strings with long chains of repeated characters. I want to add them to the binary in compressed/obfuscated form. I'm currently using a modified RLE algorithm for simplicity.

I'm using the following algorithm that works with C++20. Unfortunately now I have to support C++17 as well for business reasons. My current solution for C++17 is to put the strings on a YAML file and generate the respective .cpp "compressed" files on build time, which are then linked into the process.

Doing some research I found [this solution](https://github.com/tcsullivan/consteval-huffman) that works with Huffman but only supports C++20 (and above).

I have also seen [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32287125/compile-time-string-encryption-using-constexpr) but the "compressed" data is the same size as the raw data.

So the question is how can I rewrite the following algorithm with C++17?

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <span>
#include <sstream>

struct Array {
    const char* data;
    std::size_t size;
};

constexpr std::size_t compress( const char* data, std::size_t size, char* buf ) {
        if ( size==0 ) return 0;
        std::size_t offset = 0;
        char lastch = *data;
        std::size_t counter = 0;
        auto push = [&]() {
            if ( counter <= 3 ) {
                for ( int j=0; j<counter; ++j ) buf[offset++] = lastch;
            }
            else {
                buf[offset++] = 0;
                buf[offset++] = lastch;
                buf[offset++] = counter;
            }
            counter = 0;
        };
        lastch = data[0];
        counter = 1;
        for ( std::size_t j=1; j<size; ++j ) {
            if ( (data[j]!=lastch) || (counter==255) ) {
                push(); 
                lastch = data[j];
            }
            counter++;
        }
        push();        
        return offset;
}

template< std::size_t N > 
struct RawContainer {
    char raw_data[N];
    constexpr RawContainer( const char (&s)[N] ) {
        std::copy(s,s+N,raw_data);
    }
    constexpr operator const char* () const noexcept {
        return data;
    }
    constexpr auto data() const noexcept {
        return raw_data;
    }
    constexpr auto size() const noexcept {
        return N;
    }
};

template< auto Container >
struct StringCompressor {
    StringCompressor() noexcept {
        compress(Container.data(),Container.size(),compressed_data.data());
    }
    constexpr static auto build_size() noexcept {
        char out[Container.size()*3];
        return compress(Container.data(),Container.size(),out);
    }
    std::string str() noexcept {
        std::ostringstream out;
        out << compressed_data.size() << ": ";
        for ( std::size_t j=0; j<compressed_data.size(); ++j ) {
            out << (int)compressed_data[j] << " ";
        }
        return out.str();
    }
    std::array<char,build_size()> compressed_data;
};

template<RawContainer str>
constexpr StringCompressor<str> operator ""_x() noexcept
{
    return StringCompressor<str>();
}



auto value = "aaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbc"_x;

int main() {
    std::cout << value.str() << std::endl;
}
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/Eh9fMxW75

**Note**: the decompression algorithm was not included for simplicity.

Comment: I mean, how pretty does it have to be?  https://godbolt.org/z/8deo5jErv

Comment: Why do you have all this fancy template circumstance if all you do is handling strings? What am I missing?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Shrink the executable size 40 times is one reason.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont The compressed bytes seem to be wrong.

Comment: Just to understand your use case: In the actual production code you'll have many literals like `"aaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbc"_x` (most likely longer)? Potentially machine generated or inserted from another source, possibly through an include?

Comment: @FredHelmers /shrug, I mean, I am asking *how pretty does it have to be*.  I didn't try debug that or whatever, I just tossed together a prototype.  The use, however, would end up being awkward - and you'd need "unreferenced comdat elimination" or whatever it would be called to erase the original string from the binary.  My goal was to eliminate C++20isms and see if I could do similar operations in pure C++17 code, and I did it without even understanding what your code does, so ... yes, it'll need debugging.  In short, do you require the answer to be *pretty*?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Yes, think of embedded. Sure, I could just generate all files like Qt-moc does but the key here is nice & convenient.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Yes, not very convenient. Don't care about ugly though.

Comment: Something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/h486rWvh1) maybe?

Comment: Ah, OK, sorry if I'm slow, but do I understand correctly: Because your type conversion including compression is done at compile time, the object file does not contain the uncompressed string literals at all. That makes the object file (and the library or executable) smaller and prevents the strings from showing up at least in their literal form in the generated binaries at all, hence the size reduction you mention.

Comment: In other words, you use the compiler as a scripting engine. You could use other scripting engines which are more expressive ;-).

Comment: By the way -- I notice that the string still appears in the disassembly on godbolt, line 418. I suppose that means the attempt to eliminate the string constant from the program image was not successful, both in terms of size and information leakage?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica OH BOY now I have TWO problems... Thanks. I guess I'm reverting both to bash-generated files.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Yes, and I guess this is the story with all metatemplate programming as well. 99% of TMP can be replaced with a Jinja2 template.

Answer (score 1):

I may have a C++17 example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/sfsEnv68G) with the added benefit that it does not store the string literals in the binary. I checked for pretty long arguments (the strings in line 35 pp. in the assembler are the compressed results).

Unlike in your code, the string literal is used to initialize a constexpr array or pointer variable which is then fed to a simplified compressor class. The size has to be computed separately. That's more code per string but still, the literal only appears once. By the looks of it it can be easily generated.

The call side looks like this:

```
        constexpr const char p[] = "aaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbc";
        constexpr std::size_t comprSz = compress(p, sizeof(p), nullptr);
        constexpr Compressor<comprSz> cpr{p, sizeof(p)};
        print(cpr.comprData, comprSz);
```

It would be possible to move the size computation into another intermediary class but it does not seem possible, for whatever reason, to use plain vanilla string literals as template parameters so that the call can be a single statement, like with your user literal.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/YMWhnhdYr) is my version. The `compress` function is copied from your code with no change, the rest is lifted from my comment with some trivial modifications. The usagee is simple:

```
COMPRESSED_LITERAL("aaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbc")
```

As you can see, neither the original string nor the compression code leave any trace in the generated object.

I didn't implement `str()` because the compressed string is visible in the generated assembly. I let both compressed and uncompressed versions just output to `std::cout` just to compare the generated assembly side by side, although of course the compressed one will output nothing because of the embedded zero at the beginning.

The only downside I can think of is that you need to use a macro.